# Python Flask: Sending a form class argument from another function to prepopulate default

Tags: python, forms, flask, arguments, flask-wtforms

I need to prepopulate form fields with database (dataset) values.
The problem is that I don't know how to send the argument to the form class.

**forms.py**

```
# coding: utf-8
from db import produtosalca as produtos ##dataset imports db['table']
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextField, BooleanField, SubmitField, TextAreaField, validators, ValidationError

class ProductForm(FlaskForm,produto):
    descricao = TextField("Nome", default=produto.Descricao)        
    classificacaoFiscal = TextField("NCM", default=produto.ClassificacaoFiscal) 
    mva = TextField("MVA",default=produto.MVA)
```

app.py

```
# coding: utf-8
import os
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from flask import (
    Flask, request, send_from_directory, render_template, current_app, flash
    )
from db import produtosalca
from forms import ContactForm, ProductForm

app = Flask("alcax")

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['MEDIA_ROOT'] = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media_files')

app.secret_key = 'development key'

@app.route('/productform', methods=['GET','POST'])
def productform(product):
    form = ProductForm(request.form,product) ## here i was gonna send product
    if request.method == 'POST':
        'posted'
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('productform.html', form=form.content())
```

Well everything I tried always get me the error

```
'produto' is not defined
```

I'm a beginner in py. Have been researching all night long. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your importing produtosalca as `produtos ` , but your using it as `produto` with no S . rename `produtos` to `produto`

Comment: hey @odaialghamdi thx for the input. I forgot to delete this part. Even if i use the same name it does not work as it says AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'Descricao'. produtosalca is a db table.

Comment: Your class `table` doesn't have `Descricao` as an attribute for the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `class ProductForm(FlaskForm)` means ProductForm inherets from FlaskForm. A simple solution for your case would be as follows:

**forms.py:**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextField


class ProductForm(FlaskForm):
    descricao = TextField("Nome")
    classificacaoFiscal = TextField("NCM")
    mva = TextField("MVA")
```

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request
from forms import ProductForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'development key'


@app.route('/productform', methods=['GET','POST'])
def productform():
    form = ProductForm(descricao='default_descricao', classificacaoFiscal='default_classificacaoFiscal', mva='default_mva')
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form = ProductForm(request.form)
        # Do something with your form and redirect the user to some page.
    return render_template('productform.html', form=form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

**templates/_formhelpers.html**

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

**templates/productform.html**

```
<html !DOCTYPE>
<head>
<title>Flask WTF</title>
</head>
<body>
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method="POST" action="/submit">
    <dl>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ render_field(form.descricao, size=20) }}
    {{ render_field(form.classificacaoFiscal, size=20) }}
    {{ render_field(form.mva, size=20) }}
    </dl>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit to take into account the new queries in the comments below:**

***forms.py:***

```
class ProductForm(FlaskForm):

    descricao = TextField("Nome")
    classificacaoFiscal = TextField("NCM")
    mva = TextField("MVA")
    # ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'product' in kwargs:
            self.descricao.data = kwargs['product'][0]
            self.classificacaoFiscal.data = kwargs['product'][1]
            self.mva.data = kwargs['product'][2]
            # ...
```

***app.py:***

```
@app.route('/productform', methods=['GET','POST'])
def productform():
    # product to be retrieved from your database
    form = ProductForm(product=product)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form = ProductForm(request.form)
        # Do something with your form and redirect the user to some page.
    return render_template('productform.html', form=form)
```

Comment: hey @ettanany thanks for the help! I'm trying to understand in this case where It prepopulates the fields with default. I imagine I should change `'default_descricao'` for `produto.Descricao`, correct?

Comment: @ettanany sorry, it worked changing 'default_descricao' for produto['Descricao'] thanks so much!!!!  Now, I have 23 fields, i need to explicit them one by one or there is a more practical way?

Comment: @ChrisHawk Yes you need to change 'default_descricao' to your product's key for this field, and the same for the other fields that you have in your product object. That's was just an example.

Comment: Do you have Product model in your db file?

Comment: @ChrisHawk Take a look at the edit above for your new queries.

Comment: Hey @ettanany thanks so much man. The new edit goes a little beyond my beginner understanding but i will research this out. Again, thanks for the help! I wish I could upvote this. Is strange that people downvote and are not able to post a "better" solution.

Comment: @ChrisHawk You're welcome. Yes, It is strange! my answer might not be the best one, but I could not understand how they downvote it without posting some better alternatives. Also, I believe this question might be good for someone else, so I upvote it.